# set value of radio input codeigniter multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, multidimensional-array, radio-button

Please Help

I got something like this:

```
<input type="radio" id="radio1" name="diac[nh][question_1]" value="NECK" <?php echo set_radio('question_1', 'NECK'); ?> />
<input type="radio" id="radio2" name="diac[nh][question_1]" value="HEAD"<?php echo set_radio('question_1', 'HEAD'); ?> />
```

And i can`t make set_radio work, after form validation selected value disappears. How to make it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from the documentation

```
The first parameter must contain the name of the checkbox
```

your input is named `diac[nh][question_1]` while you use `question_1` in your function